# Where is the actual link for Windows Store so that I can create developer account

Tags: windows-store

I wanted to find the actual URL where I can sign up for a developer account, but searching for hours in the Google and MSDN, I cannot find the real page where I can start registering for a Store Developer Account. I searched in MSDN website and found this url:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh868184

But this URL makes me more frustrated. It just TALKS. It says how to register for an account but it does not give me the link to the page where I can actually visit and register for an account. That is really ridiculous. Anyway, would anyone please help me about whats going on ? Why the Store Sign up url is not available in the search engines.

By the way, I am searching from my Windows 7 PC. I dont have Windows 8 installed yet. Is that the reason why I cant find out the real sign up URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install VS2012 on a windows8 machine, when you try to create a store app it will ask you to create a developer account.

That's how I did it